# Meaning of “recht gelassen zu”

Tags: idiom

> Normalerweise geht es in Hannover recht gelassen zu.

Is *recht gelassen zu* a fixed expression, meaning ‘very relaxing’?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*zu* is the prefix of the separable verb [*zugehen*](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/zugehen), and is therefore placed at the end of the sentence. *Recht gelassen* means ‘quite relaxing’. The whole sentence translates as

> In Hannover things are normally quite relaxing.

Comment: The adverb _recht_ doesn’t mean ‘very’, though; it’s rather something like ‘quite’. (Cc @dulcecream)

Comment: @chirlu Just edited.

Comment: I would argue that *relaxed* is more appropriate in this case as *es geht gelassen zu* indicates a state of the place not an effect on whoever is there.